# Implementing the right conditions for a yum command for centos5 in Ansible

Tags: linux, yum, ansible, centos-5

I'm currently working with a centos5 host and I have to install some packages with yum.. unfortunately, as far as I know, centos5 doesn't support Ansible's yum module so I have to use the 'command' or 'shell' modules and 'hard code' everything by myself.

My question is.. what are the conditions I should implement to make a command/shell behave like Ansible's yum module and make it as much 'indepotent' as possible?

For the moment this is what I came up with:

#### When installing/updating a package

```
- name: INSTALL (C5) - Install package
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: yum -y install <package>
  register: output_install
  changed_when: '"Installing:" in output_install["stdout"] or "Updating:" in output_install["stdout"]'
  failed_when: output_install["stdout"] is regex("No package.*available")
```

#### When removing a package

```
- name: UNINSTALL (C5) - Remove package
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: yum -y remove <package>
  register: output_remove
  changed_when: '"Erasing" in output_remove["stdout"]
  failed_when: "No Packages marked for removal" in output_remove["stdout"]'
```

Do you guys have any suggestion or have already dealt with this problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be easier to install python 2.7.9 on your outdated target and use it as the [ansible python interpreter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html) so as to use the `yum` ansible module directly rather than reinventing the wheel. See for example https://github.com/scalp42/python-2.7.x-on-Centos-5.x